# how to create alphabet generating line in php

Tags: php

so i'm trying to make an md5 dictionary and i wanted to go through the easiest way which of course is creating an array with the alphabet that i want in then setting a loooooop and each time i will create the md5 of each alphabet (echo $array[%SOMEVALUEHERE%]) but the thing is , it is easy to do the first row of alphabet (a,b,c....) buuuuut when i want to repeat them (aa,ab,ac......) i can't seem to find a way that doesnt need me to write a 100000 line code , so can anyone direct me to the correct way ?

Comment: Even allowing for that, it's pretty unclear what you want to achieve, or where you're up to so far. Please present some sample input data, the expected output of your program (based on the given input data), the code you've written so far, and the current output of that code.

Comment: @SuperMarioMC98 ADyson is correct that in its current form it is very difficult to understand exactly what you've tried so far, as well as why it doesn't work. Please do take a look at some of the links provided and reformat your question so that others are more easily able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding properly, the goal is to generate strings up to a certain length, with each letter combination?

```
Ex:
a, b, c...
aa, ab, ac...
aaa, aab, aac...
```

If that's the case you could build an array with the 26 letters and pass them to a recursive function that builds strings up to the length that you are looking for. This is a quick example using abc and up to length 4. Its just echo'ing out the strings, but instead of the echo you could do whatever you like with them:

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c');

buildString('', $arr, 1);
buildString('', $arr, 2);
buildString('', $arr, 3);
buildString('', $arr, 4);

function buildString($currString, $arr, $targetLength)
{
    foreach($arr as $letter)
    {
        $tmpString = $currString . $letter;

        if(strlen($tmpString) != $targetLength)
        {
            buildString($tmpString, $arr, $targetLength);
        }
        else
        {
            echo $tmpString . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Would probably need to do some tweaking on that for your purposes, but that's just an example to give you a general idea of how to approach it.

Comment: and if i make the length bigger and i use md5 to encript it , i would be able to generate a dictionary

Comment: Yep - you should be able to set the length to as long as you want it to go, and then instead of the 'echo' line, add the word to an array or encrypt it or whatever you would like to do.